# How can I fill all space of a div 100% with 3 divs with the same size?

Tags: css, html

I have a `div.wrap` with 100% width and 3 `div` inside it.
I need the 3 `div` have the same width and could fill all the space of `div.wrap`.

I've tried to do something like that:
html:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrap{width:100%;position:relative;}
.wrap div{width:33.3%;float:left;}
```

But on the absolute right side, i have something like 2px blank, I need to fill all space. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Even if you already picked the correct answer, I just want to help, not the upvotes, have a look at my answer, it don't use "hacky" percent decimals, also, the children `div`s will take the full height of their parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can only set the width of an element with a maximum precision of `1px`, there may be one div that is larger than the others and you can't really avoid this. Having said that, to make the last div fill the remaining `1-2px`, do this:

```
.wrap #div3 {width:33.4%;}
```

where `#div3` is the id of the last `div` (or any of the divs, but only one).

Comment: Adding a class selector in `.wrap #div3` is redundant, since `#div3` is unique.

Answer (score 2):

Set the width of the last div in such a way that the sum of widths equal 100:

```
.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap div {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
.wrap div:last-child {
    width: 33.4%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/z4Lc6/)

Answer (score 2):

By simulating the Tables behaviours we can easily achieve this:

html:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrap{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrap div{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Feel Free to add some background color and stuff to the `.wrap div` to check the sizes.

Comment: The columns will not be same width then.

Comment: you're right, I actually tested with 1 character only and thought they would behave like so

Comment: Hmmm, the idea isn't bad; set 33.3% width on first two cells, the last one fills the remaining space!

Comment: Fixed it, I remember I used this before XD, its "better" because the div's will take the full height of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks here is another approach using a different fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/c5bR9/

```
.wrap div {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
}
.wrap div:last-child {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 66.6%;
}
```

I've had troubles in the past with partial percentages (mainly Internet Explorer) where they calculate to be larger than 100% — meaning your third column will drop down. The above makes use of a div's natural habit of filling up space, and the natural habit of margin to eat into this auto width calculation.