# CSS 33.3333% leaves a pixel

Tags: html, css

Frustrating problem, I have a div with 3 other div's inside that each should be 33% (one third). The problem is that i always have an extra pixel.

### I tried the following.

- 33.333333333%
- 33.3334%
- calc (100% / 3)

This is an image showing the problem

[image]

This is my HTML

```
<div class="navigation">

    <div class="navigation-item">
        <div class="navigation-item-inner">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50">
            <h5>Running</h5>
            Whatever fits your need
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navigation-item">
        <div class="navigation-item-inner">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50">
            <h5>Running</h5>
            Whatever fits your need
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navigation-item">
        <div class="navigation-item-inner">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50">
            <h5>Running</h5>
            Whatever fits your need
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.navigation
{
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
}

.navigation-item
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 33.3333%;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
    
.navigation-item-inner
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### Edit

Thanks for the fiddle, I updated it to match the problem

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/h8p4A/3/

Comment: What CSS is on the image?

Comment: You have `display: table`, I don't think you need height.

Comment: wrap these 3 into a 100% height wrapper and set the background there

Comment: Can you replicate this in a fiddle?

Comment: or just use 33% + 33% + 34% for the third div

Comment: I ***just*** answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22964039/87015

Answer (score 4):

It's a problem of rounding. You could set Height of container (so "navigation") to 99% and then set height of each inside element simpy to 33%. I think that could be a reasonable tradeoff.....

Comment: Thanks! not a bad idea.. I used height: 101% on the parent element with an overflow: hidden! Stupid that rounding can cause that issue. Is this a common problem?

Comment: Yes, is very common and I think it is pretty inevitable..... it's simply math! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've specified the exact pixel height that the percentages is based on (I assume you're using the window height here, so you'll have no control over this), you'll always have rounding errors of at least one pixel. When approximating 1/3 using percentages it's even worse since you don't know how the browser will round the percentage.

To handle extra pixels in vertical rounding, I'd suggest you just accept it and use a background-color of the parent container that match or approximate the color of the bottom edge of the last item. To make the issue less apparent.

For floated elements filling the width, I'd suggest you make sure that you never use decimals in the percentages (or only 0.5 % and make sure the parent container is an even number of pixels wide, using max-width etc.), so that a rounding error won't cause the last item to wrap.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Very clear.. I used a height of 101% and overflow: hidden.. Would that be a good practice way of solving this issue? + updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h8p4A/3/

Comment: If you prefer potentially clipping a few pixels on the last item over a potential 1 pixel gap; sure making the content sligtly too big and hide the overflow would work.

Comment: Note that if you try to fill the space horizontally with floated elements, making the content too wide might not work because it could cause the last item to float down.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use :last-child and make the last `.navigation-item` 33.4%?

```
.navigation-item:last-child
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 33.4%;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: this wont necessarily work, eg < 100px wide will still cause a round down.